# Event after partial is rendered?

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation

I have a View with a template that contains a `{{partial partialName}}` helper. The given partial produces markup for Foundation tooltips *after* `$(document).foundation();` has been run by way of the run loop, which means the tooltips don't get picked up.

Foundation's recommendation for dynamically generated content is to reinitialize foundation.

I've tried doing this, without success, by making use of the following:

- `didInsertElement`
- Ember.run.scheduleOnce ... 'afterRender'
- extending the built-in `{{partial}}` helper

How can I run a function after the contents of a Partial are rendered into the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing I hadn't accounted for is that the partials relied on data being loaded asynchronously. I needed to reinitialize foundation **after the bound data was available**.

Within a callback, I made use of the run loop:

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
  // Reinitialize Foundation components that have been rendered since data loaded
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

didInsertElement works on the view where your partial is coming from.  So assuming your partial is in the index view, we would create an index view:

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({

  // or didInsertElement: function(){}

  foundationizeIt: function(){
    $(document).foundation();
  }.on('didInsertElement') 
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jasisawi/1/edit